# How to perform a def function using dash html core component button

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a simple code like the below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, Date, Float
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)




def my_DB_func():

    .............

    """Connection to sql-server Part"""
    # connect db
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://bbbbb-aaaaa\zzzzzzzxxx/toolDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
    connection = engine.connect()

    ................

    # Close the connection
    connection.close()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So all I need When Click this button kust do the `my_DB_func()`

About this function it's just a code contains about more than 800 lines that's create a database and export some excel files using `to_csv` and `to_sql` functions

So how to perform the `@Callback` function to do a `def` funtion

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use thise simple @Call-Back and it works:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='body-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='button', component_property='n_clicks')]
)

def update_output(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        return my_DB_func()
```